# How to undo local changes in git

Tags: git

This question has been asked before, however none of the suggested solutions work for me.
Here are the things I tried so far.

### 1st Method

```
git reset --hard
```

When I check for

```
git status
```

it would still show me all the local changes as before with the following message.
On branch hotfix/fixedunittests
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/hotfix/fixedunittests'.

> Changes not staged for commit: (use "git add ..." to update what
>   will be committed) (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes
>   in working directory) modified:
>   webapp/src/main/java/en/karmatik/DuplicateCustomer.java

### 2nd Method

```
git checkout .. <file>
```

Same message as before

### 3rd Method

```
git stash save
git stash drop
```

Still no change

### 4th Method

```
git reset HEAD
git checkout .
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: Try `git checkout -- <file>`.

Comment: ´Tried already without any success. btw I am running the "git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1" on a Windows 7 64Bit PC.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure as you only have the version `git checkout <file>` in your list (so, without the `--`).

Comment: One of these methods should work; there's something fishy going on here.

Comment: @fge I feel the same. Could it be that the git version I am using(1.9.5.msysgit.1) is buggy?

Comment: Is DuplicateCustomer.java a untracked/newly added file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that you work on Windows this could be related to how git is treating line endings. Try this:

1. disable autocrlf `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
2. fix the file manually so that all `crlf` are changed to `lf`
3. enable autocrlf `git config --global core.autocrlf true`